# tapply function in R

Tags: r, tapply

I am trying to apply my moving average function to one variable as follow:

```
Fonction.mm <- function(x)
{
  filter(x, poids, sides=1, method="conv")
}

numero<-1:nrow(data)
tapply(numero, data$td, Fonction.mm)
```

`data$td` which is a character variable with 2 categories.

But this does not work getting the error:

```
Error in tapply(numero, data$td, Fonction.mm) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Give us example data for `numero` and `data$td`. Even then, the error is clear. `numero` and `data$td` must be of the same length.

Comment: td val
2 38.553
2 2.313
1 7.559
1 95.648
1 7.559

Comment: td val
2 38.553
2 2.313
1 7.559
1 95.648
1 7.559
val is the numeric variable onto i do my moving average.

Comment: numero is the number of row of the overall data

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

In tapply the first argument is numeric and the second is a factor and the third the function you use.

If you want to do a numeric averaging on td the form is tapply(data$td, your-factor, fonction.mm).

Also what is your "poids" ?

Comment: Thanks I have change the syntax but now i get : Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.1 Mb  / poids is the chosen time of my average mean

Comment: R doesn't really free up memory. Use rm(object1, object2, ...) to remove those object which use alot of memory. Or start a new R session. Also choose the 64bit version of R if you have more then 4gb of memory avaivable. If these don't help you need to improve your code or get more memory to your computer (which probably isn't the issue).